# Dependency injection thread safety

Tags: c#, multithreading, singleton, asp.net-web-api

Is it OK to mix different lifetime of `ISerializer` and `ICacheProvider` in this case? I am using Unity DI. In this case, whenever `ICacheProvider` is needed, Unity will always give the same instance (singleton) but `ISerializer` will always be a new instance. I am not sure if it would be OK to have `ISerializer` as a singleton as well in an ASP.NET Web API environment.

```
public class MyCacheProvider : ICacheProvider
{
   private readonly ISerializer _serializer;

   public MyCacheProvider(ISerializer serializer)
   {
       _serializer = serializer;
   }
}
```

Serializer implementation:

```
public class JilSerializer : ISerializer
    {
        public string Serialize<T>(T instance)
        {
            return JSON.Serialize(instance);
        }

        public T Deserialize<T>(string input)
        {
            return JSON.Deserialize<T>(input);
        }
    }
```

Configuring DI Container to provide instances:

```
container.RegisterType<ISerializer, JilSerializer>();
            container.RegisterType<ICacheProvider, MyCacheProvider>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `MyCacheProvider` will hold an instance of `JilSerializer` and since your `MyCacheProvider` is a singleton - there's going to be an instance of `JilSerializer` around forever as well.

As it's apparently fine for your `ICacheProvider` to use the same serializer throughout the lifetime of the app, and the implementation looks completely fine for sharing an instance, I don't see any reason why you can't just make `ISerializer` a singleton too.

I think that this isn't quite a captive dependency as the default lifetime of `ISerializer` is transient but it's certainly a related topic that you can read about on [Mark Seemann's blog](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).